# Java SOAPUI XML sorting arrays or someting else

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, soapui

I am building tests in SoapUI. I have a very large response (>3500 duties). For that response I need to build a request and execute that request. Currently the code (Java) works, but I would like to optimize the code.

For each Duty I build a request to get additional employee data and execute it using a for next loop. Below is an example of the large XML response that I get.

```
<DUTIES>
    <DUTY>
        <EMPNO>1</EMPNO>
        <LOCATION>AMS</BASE_STATION>
        <ACTUALTIME>2019-02-20T06:00:00</ACTUALTIME>        
        <POSITIONING_CODE>1</POSITIONING_CODE>
    </DUTY>
    <DUTY>
        <EMPNO>2</EMPNO>
        <LOCATION>RTM</BASE_STATION>
        <ACTUALTIME>2019-02-20T06:00:00</ACTUALTIME>        
        <POSITIONING_CODE/>
    </DUTY>
    <DUTY>
        <EMPNO>1</EMPNO>
        <LOCATION>AMS</BASE_STATION>
        <ACTUALTIME>2019-02-21T06:00:00</ACTUALTIME>        
        <POSITIONING_CODE>1</POSITIONING_CODE>
    </DUTY>
</DUTIES>
```

As you can see from the sample the same employee is multiple times in the response, so currently I am calling the request multiple time for the same employee. I would like to optimize this.

In SoapUI I can use the statement:

```
String[] emps = resp.getNodeValues("/Duties/Duty/string(EMPNO)");
String[] locs = resp.getNodeValues("/Duties/Duty/string(LOCATION)");
String[] tims = resp.getNodeValues("/Duties/Duty/string(ACTUALTIME)");
```

Then I would like to sort the arrays on emps and only build a request to get additional employee data when the employee changes. This will make the code much faster.

Now my questions:
What is the best way to do this? Work with multidimensional array and sort them? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

Said

Comment: Too broad - "Then I would like to sort the arrays on emps..." - so go and do that - what is the question? When you get a problem with your code stackoverflow.com maybe can help... or do you expect to get a solution instead of working on it by your self?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an instance of `java.util.HashMap<String,String>` or `java.util.HashMap<Long,String>` depending on which datatype is returned, when you retrive the empno.

Just blindly do a `map.put(empno,null)` for each duty element, and you will only have each employee in the hashmap once afterwards, as each additional addition of the same key will overwrite the existing.

After that, simply

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

As I see it, you really don't need to sort anything to get there.